# redirect to My Account page when user logs in the first time

Tags: drupal, redirect, user-profile

I want to change the way user logins work on my Drupal site. Currently, if an admin creates the user account, this user is redirected to the profile setup page when logging in for the first time. But I want to redirect the user to their My Account page instead. How can I do this. Is there any module for this? If yes, please let me know or tell me the file name where I have to make the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The humorously named, but useful [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module should do the trick. The [Login destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module also might be an alternative.